# Combine Pandas' startwith and isin

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to get dataframe (all columns) where specific `isin` value appears only in `startwith` columns.
Currently I have codes that do both steps seperate but need them to happen in one line:

```
Dataframe:
   col1  col2   filter_col3  filter_col4
0     0     0             1            0
1     0     0             0            1
2     0     0             0            0

#get only columns that start with str
filter_col = [c for c in df if c.startwith('filter_')]

#return row when 1 appears in any of the columns
df[df.isin([1]).any(axis=1)]

Expected result:
    col1  col2   filter_col3  filter_col4
 0     0     0             1            0
 1     0     0             0            1
```

Comment: With your approach you can do `df[df.loc[:,df.columns.str.startswith("filter_")].eq(1).any(1)]` , columns support startswith with a `str` accessor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `pd.DataFrame.filter`:

```
# also `.eq(1)` instead of `.isin([1])`
df[df.filter(regex='^filter_').isin([1]).any(1)]
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2  filter_col3  filter_col4
0     0     0            1            0
1     0     0            0            1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `df.filter` with `Series.eq`:

```
In [2567]: df[df.filter(like='filter').eq(1).any(1)]
Out[2567]: 
   col1  col2  filter_col3  filter_col4
0     0     0            1            0
1     0     0            0            1
```